# out of space SAS studio engine V9- MAC

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I was trying to practice with a dataset having more than 100K rows and my SAS UE shows error as out of space while trying statistical analysis,after some google search I found some solutions like extending disk space in VM and cleaning work libraries(I did clean the work library using "proc datasets library=WORK kill; run; quit;" but the issue remains same) but I am not sure how to increase the disk space, or redirecting work library to local storage in my Mac. There are no proper guidelines I have seen/understood from google search. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the cores on the VM to be 2 and increase the RAM space in the Oracle VB settings. You cannot increase the size of the VM and 100K rows should not be problematic unless you're not cleaning up processes.

Yes, SAS UE does have a tendency to not clean up after crashes so eventually if you've crashed it multiple times you'll have to reinstall to clean up. You can get around this by reassigning the work library. A quick way to do this is in projects that will be affecting it set the USER library to your myfolders or another space on your computer.

```
libname user '/folders/myfolders/tempWSpace';
```

Make sure you first create the folder under myfolders. Then any single level data set (no libname) will automatically be stored in user library and you should be ok to run your code.

Comment: Hi Reeza Thanks for your reply, But now I am getting a different issue. I can't even log in to the SAS EU because of the error "UNABLE TO CREATE SESSION TEMP DIRECTORY'. Is this becoz of the out of space issue or do I have to update the SAS UE?. . thanks.

Comment: Go to the communities.sas.com site and you'll see a message and any updates about issues with SAS UE. I believe there's an issue with Chrome 67 at the moment and using a different browser solves the issue, but the SAS release is the official notice.

Comment: Hi Thank you.. I updated my SAS UE and set USER library...it is working fine.